# Overall percentage difference

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology, percentages

In a corpus of text the expected letter frequency might be:

- e = 30%
- t = 30%
- a = 20%
- o = 20%

Actual recorded frequency:

- e = 90%
- t = 10%
- a = 0%
- o = 0%

I want to know the OVERALL percentage difference (not the average difference) between the expected frequencies and the actual frequencies, how would this be done? e.g: "Overall there is a 35% difference between what we expected our frequency count to be and our actual frequencies".

90% of the letters are e, but we expected only 30% of them to be e. So there is a 60% difference.

But this doesn't seem right to me, if it was expected to be 30% but we've got 90%, then that is 200% difference isn't it?!

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your definition of "percent difference."  Some people use this to refer to the *point difference* between two percentages.  (That is, $90\% - 30\% = 60\% \text{ percent difference}$).

However, other people refer to percent difference as a specific fraction:
$$\Delta\% = \frac{x - x_0}{x_0}\times100\%$$
(where $x$ is a given reading, and $x_0$ is the reference reading).

It depends on your specific application which definition you should use.

Comment: I need a single percentage score, from 0-100% that tells me the difference between what we expected the results to be, and the actual recorded results. Surely this is done all the time by accountants when calculating overall percentage gains/loss?